# Keychain certificate

Tags: iphone

My certificate (.p12 file) when imported to the keychain gives an error (This certificate has expired) what should i do ?

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1618.html) should help you out.

> If your certificate has expired, renew it at the iPhone Portal, download it, and double-click it to add it to your Keychain. If it's "signed by an unknown authority", download the "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations" certificate from the Certificates section of the iPhone Portal and double-click it to add it to your Keychain.

Comment: ARGGGGGGGG ty so much, I am going to go make accounts to give you more upvotes. Its not so bad but man is it frustrating to have these problems.